# SSIS: adding a column to a destination table after import

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package that I used to import excel data, I need to add a column to the table when I import the data, however, the column, is contrived data joined from another table that already exists in the sql server database.

Does anybody know how I would even begin to do this?

I've tried "derived column" however, the data that populates the column is not derived from the source excel data, rather, a join from the data to that other table.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a view for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lookup in addition to the methods from @HLGEM

Answer (score 2):

I know of two methods. One you can use a merge join in the dataflow. This tends to be a slow because you have to sort both the sources for the merge. If your data set is not large this might not be too bad though.

If your data source is large, I prefer to import the data to a work table in one data flow first.  Then the datasource in the second data flow (the ones that imports to the production table) would be a query that joins the worktable to the existing table you want to grab other information from. This is more timeconsuming to set up, but here we never import anything without a work table because it maskes going back to research data import issues so much easier. It also makes it easier to clean up the data before import in my opinion as I am not a fan of doing the clean up in the data flow.

Comment: I tend to agree with the second solution.  Stage the data and do the work you need in SQL Server.  However, you can do all of it in the context of the data flow using merge joins or lookups.

Comment: I know you can do it all in terms of dataflows, I find that they are harder to maintain than using t-sql to clean data.

Comment: Agreed.  It is better to stage the data and use t-sql to clean the data.